# Has anyone else experienced issues with the apex job scheduler?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

The follow scheduled apex jobs highlighted below (in yellow) are configured to run daily, and were scheduled to start this morning - however, they have not ran since 10/12/13.  Has anyone else experienced similar issues?  These jobs have been running previously, and none have bee modified recently, I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the Winter 14 release?

[image]

[image]

In addition, we've ran each of the highlighted jobs manually (via dev console), and each completed successfully, NO run-time exceptions were reported.

I did not find any similar issues on the SF Trust site.  I've opened a support case with Salesforce, but wanted to see if any other organizations are experiencing similar issues.

Thanks

Comment: I had similar issue and i was wondering how you had resolved, please advise -srini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce developer support mentioned the Winter 14 release window negatively impacted a number of organization's scheduled jobs.  Although the scheduler successfully queues the jobs, it was not executing them.  No error handling around the scheduler is provided by SF, you'll have to create your own monitoring to help ensure maintenance windows don't inadvertently kill your scheduled jobs.  The fix provided is to simply reschedule your failed jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Check here for Salesforce related bugs: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index

Also, based on your APEX Job list, all Job Status seems to be success.

One thing might help, is to go to Monitoring --> Debug Logs and add yourself as monitored Users.

When the Scheduled Jobs runs next time, you will be able to analyze full stack trace of Debug Logs for Scheduled APEX.

Comment: I have reviewed the known issues site, in my post I called it the "SF trust site" - sorry about that.  Regarding the status, yeah the ones that ran are reporting success - however, the apex schedule does not seem to be executing the other jobs.  I've debugged already, but I'll look this method - thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below query and check if the jobs have run.I have seen few cases where it does not show on the UI.

SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType,TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC